# RS232 Alicat and Labview communication drop

Tags: serial-port, labview, serial-communication

At the moment I have a problem I cannot pin down. Seemingly at random my communication with my RS232 Alicat Device will get held up. It will get held up somewhere in the read or write process and be unable to complete it. Upon closing the VI I will get a "Resetting VI" error in Labview 2020. I am using 7 of the 9 RS232 ports. My question is:

1. How do I fix this problem so that I do not get a communication drop OR (more likely)
2. How do I code the system such that I can catch and move through this problem or reset the connection. Something of a VISA read/write timeout?  Open to ideas on how to move past the block

Here is what I have gathered about the problem:

1. Windows 10, I’ve tested everything on multiple computers. It happens no matter what.
2. It happens at random. It might happen twice within 20 minutes or not for a couple of hours.
3. I have never experienced the error when probing the line. I don’t know if that is a clue, or if that speaks to the randomness of the problem
4. Baud Rate = 9600, Prior to this I was running at 19,200 and experienced equivalent issues. The manufacturer recommended lowering the baud rate to reduce noise. I have also isolated the cable from other parts of the hardware. At this point noise on the connection is not an issue, but I am still experiencing the error.
5. My buffer size is 1000 bytes.
6. By termination character is \r. I cannot imagine a scenario where it fails to read a termination character due to the size of my buffer
7. I'm querying it every 50ms. Far below the threshold of a standard timeout. Too much?

What I am currently testing.

Due to how my code block is setup I cannot yet confirm if it is getting locked up on the read or write block or both. I'm attempting to isolate the problem with only minor modifications to see if I can isolate it.

Attached is slimmed down version of my code that I isolated the error to.

[image]

Comment: There is no attached code (I guess you forgot to post it somehow)...

Comment: Don't know how i missed that. Its attached now.

Comment: I see that there is used some library for communication. Is that yours custom implemented, or it is from some toolkit? Those are not plained VISA Read/Write functions, right?

Comment: It looks like the system is closing the visa ports. Probably, if you held them too long. Check, how long you keep them and if they are still open, if the connection breaks. If they are closed, it is probably the Windows ressource manager (or what this thing is called).

Comment: You seem to have a producer consumer structure. The error, if the queue is eaten empty or if it overflows seems to be unhandled. Why do you use a timed loop for the producer loop? Try replacing it by a while loop with wait=f(items in queue). The more items are in the queue, the slower it runs, the less the faster.

Comment: I fixed this with 2 things at once, but i dont know which one actually did it. I switched all the timed loops to standard while loops. I also had to change a windows usb setting that would turn off my usb connections after they were inactive for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced similar problems with some RS232 devices from different suppliers. The (quite bad) solution was to connect and disconnect for each communication command. The question would be what sample rate you need.

Another idea is to replace that device with an ethernet device. If I am not mistaken Alicat supplies those with Modbus (TCP).

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be specific to windows/my laptop. There is a USB setting that disables inactive USB's after a certain amount of time. The setting to disable the timeout was unavailable through the control panel on my laptop, though it was available on my coworkers. I had to use powershell commands to change the setting